# SDP Origin attribute ('o') - is this the IP of the client, or the RTP server?

Tags: sdp

In an SDP message, the ["Origin" ('o') attribute](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4566#section-5.2) is defined as:

```
o=<username> <sess-id> <sess-version> <nettype> <addrtype> <unicast-address>
```

Where `<unicast-address>` has the following definition:

> is the address of the machine from which the session was created.

However, I'm unclear on whether this should be the IP of the client, or the RTP server. For example, if the client is running VLC on IP 1.1.1.1, and the RTP server is serving media from 2.2.2.2, should the `<unicast-address>` be set to 1.1.1.1, or 2.2.2.2?

Answer (score 1):

I take it to mean the machine which creates the session and actually generates the SDP message, i.e. not the RTP server (the address of the RTP endpoints are defined elsewhere in the message). That's how I've always implemented it in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The unicast address is of the server thats creating the RTP session. Usually it carries the IP address but for reasons of obfuscation the IP can be switched to FQDN or even something relatively obscure that for purposes of debugging can only be understood by the application developers.

It doesn't have any significance w.r.t to SDP / RTP processing.